# How can I write an inner class as a lambda expression?

Tags: java

I am attempting to replace the inner class:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                
                red.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                });
                green.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                });
                blue.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                });
                clear.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(null);
                });
            }
```

in this program:

```
package com.IST242Apps;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ColorFrame extends JFrame{
JButton red, green, blue, clear;

public ColorFrame() { //frame parameters
    super("ColorFrame");
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flo);
    
    //create buttons
    red = new JButton("RED");
    add(red);
    green = new JButton("GREEN");
    add(green);
    blue = new JButton("BLUE");
    add(blue);
    clear = new JButton("CLEAR");
    add(clear);

    //Something starts here -- the inner class?
    ActionListener act = new ActionListener() { // 
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { //when button is clicked
                
                red.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED); //make red
                });
                green.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN); //make green
                });
                blue.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE); //make blue
                });
                clear.addActionListener(e -> {
                    getContentPane().setBackground(null); //make clear
                });
            }
        };
    //comment: something ends here
        
    //execute lambda expressions
    red.addActionListener(act); 
    green.addActionListener(act);
    blue.addActionListener(act);
    clear.addActionListener(act);
    
    setVisible(true); //make visible
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ColorFrame();
    }
}
```

as a lambda expression. However, I'm confused on how to actually replace inner classes with lambda expressions as I've never done so before.

If you could also explain how lambda expressions work, as what ive seen on w3schools.

// numbers.forEach( (n) -> { System.out.println(n); } );

```
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(9);
    numbers.add(8);
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.forEach( (n) -> { System.out.println(n); } );
```

(1) you reference something. (numbers)
(2) express some command. (forEach)
(3) set a parameter (n)
(4) express some code to be executed. ({System.out.println(n);})
// is n just referring to a non-existant variable?

Comment: Just move the existing lambdas out of the inner class. The present code doesn't make sense. You don't need to add action listeners inside an action listener.

Comment: You've already done it inside your anonymous class.  Just get rid of `act` and the `actionPerformed()` method and your code will work fine.  Your current code adds an action listener, and that action listener adds more action listeners that do what you actually want.  Why not just directly add the action listeners in the first place?

Comment: [Java 8: Lambdas, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1.html) , [Java SE 8: Lambda Quick Start](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) , [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent lambda expression is:

```java
ActionListener act = event -> { //when button is clicked

    red.addActionListener(e -> {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED); //make red
    });
    green.addActionListener(e -> {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN); //make green
    });
    blue.addActionListener(e -> {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE); //make blue
    });
    clear.addActionListener(e -> {
        getContentPane().setBackground(null); //make clear
    });
};
```

Comment: As long as you only have one statement, you don't need the extra `{}`